# Special Characters in Cocos2D-X CCLabelTTF

Tags: special-characters, cocos2d-x, cclabelttf

Hi I want to create CCLabelTTF with a string that contains special characters here is some example

```
CCLabelTTF* pLabelDuracion = CCLabelTTF::create("Duración de Periodo", "Arial", 20,CCSize(),kCCTextAlignmentLeft);
```

or

```
CCLabelTTF* pLabelPsswd = CCLabelTTF::create("Contraseña", "Arial", 20,CCSize(),kCCTextAlignmentLeft);
```

Please show me how to display this characters in my app  ("ñ","´",etc)

I'm coding in visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your cpp file encoding to UTF in visual studio